# On function doesn't work where the live function did

Tags: jquery

I've read that the live function is deprecated and one should use the on method instead.

So I edited my code from

```
$('form').live('submit', function (event) {})
```

to

```
$('form').on('submit', function (event) {})
```

and it doesn't work anymore :-) I'm wondering why ?

BTW the form element is added dynamically.

Comment: See the equivalency cases in the documentation (this *is* [documented](http://api.jquery.com/on/) with [conversion discussion](http://api.jquery.com/live/)). That `on` is **not** using Delegated Events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to attach the event handler to an element which exists in the DOM on page load:

```
$('body').on('submit', 'form', function(event) {
 ...
});
```

You should substitute `body` for an element which is closer to the `form`, this way the event only has to bubble up one level, thus increasing performance, for example:-

```
<div id="container">
  <form>
    ...
  </form>
</div>
```

Then you would use:

```
$('#container').on('submit', 'form', function(event) {
  ...
});
```

All of this information can be found in the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: I also used $(this) to get the form object. How can I get here ?

Comment: `$(this)` would still reference the `form` object

Answer (score 2):

Use this instead

```
$('body').on('submit', 'form', function (event) {})
```

Check section **Direct and delegated events** on the jquery documentation for [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method

Comment: I also used $(this) to get the form object. How can I get here ?